# How to neglect automatically generated attributes and add new attributes in its place?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm creating one XML node using serialization as below,using C#

```
<node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<childNode1><![CDATA[some file name]]></childNode1>
<childNode2><![CDATA[some file name]]></childNode2>
</node >
```

How to avoid attributes  `"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` for 'node'and add other attribute in its place??
So that resultant node should look like:

```
<node name="xyz" group="abc">
```

The code I used is:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddressDetails details = new AddressDetails();
        Serialize(details);
    }

    static public void Serialize(AddressDetails details)
    {

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressDetails));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, details);
    }
}
public class AddressDetails
{ 
    [XmlElement("Street")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CityName")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Address address;
    public AddressDetails()
    {
        StreetName = "XYZ";
        City = "Pune";
    }
    public System.Xml.XmlCDataSection MyStringCDATA
    {
        get
        {
            return new System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection("load and run");
        }
        set
        {  }
    }
}
public class Address
{
    [XmlAttribute("HouseNo")]
    public int HouseNo { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("floor")]
    public int floor { get; set; }
    public Address()
    {
        HouseNo = 204;
        floor = 2;
    }
}
```

The purpose of creating this xml is, I want to create the same node template multiple times, but each node name is different and i want to give the node name dynamically. 
For eg. in the above code the node name is "AddressDetails" as set through the class name.....now for next time i want the node name as "AddressDetails_John"..."AddressDetails_Harry".. is there any provision to make it dynamic in this way? –

thanks...

Comment: How are you creating this XML?  With `XmlSerializer`?  `XDocument.Save`?

Comment: Can you show the code you already have?  Or the classes you are serializing?

Comment: One more problem encountered was; i was trying to set attributes to a node using the class "Address" , but was unable to. The attributes are not reflected in the generated xml file...

Comment: Your sample classes do not have properties `name` and `group`.  I answered the question using the actual classes just provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To suppress writing of the standard XML namespaces, pass an empty `XmlSerializerNamespaces` to [`XmlSerializer.Serialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z5zfc6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

   ```
       XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
       ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
       serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
   ```
2. To add an attribute: a property will be serialized to XML as an attribute when it is marked with the [`[XmlAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, for instance:

   ```
       [XmlAttribute("name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   ```

Thus, in your example, if you want `AddressDetails.Street` and `AddressDetails.CityName` to be attributes, you could do:

```
public class AddressDetails
{
    [XmlAttribute("Street")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("CityName")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public Address address;

    public AddressDetails()
    {
        StreetName = "XYZ";
        City = "Pune";
    }

    public System.Xml.XmlCDataSection MyStringCDATA
    {
        get
        {
            return new System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection("load and run");
        }
        set
        { }
    }
}
```

And, to omit standard namespaces when serializing, you could add the following static method:

```
    public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, string filename, bool omitStandardNamespaces = false)  // Change the default to true if you prefer.
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;        // For cosmetic purposes.
            settings.IndentChars = "    "; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                if (omitStandardNamespaces)
                {
                    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
                }
                else
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of creating this xml is, I want to create the same node template multiple times, but each node name is different and i want to give   the node name dynamically. For eg. in the above code the node name is "AddressDetails" as set through the class name.....now for next time i want the node name as "AddressDetails_John"..."AddressDetails_Harry".. is there any provision to make it dynamic in this way?